# check value of a field with a list of values in Elastic query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I'm looking for something like "in" command of SQL query language but in the elastic search query

I have written something like this and I want to know how to pass a list of messageThreadIds instead of only a specific value!

```
            BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("messageThread:\"" + messageThreadId + "\""));
    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("isDeleted:false"));
    queryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("excludedUsers:\"" + receiverUserId + "\""));
    queryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("sender:\"" + receiverUserId + "\""));
    if (sendTime != null) {
        if (sendTimeNanos != null) {
            queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(
                    "sendTime:>" + sendTime +
                            " OR (sendTime: " + sendTime + " AND sendTimeNanos:>" + sendTimeNanos + ")")
            );
        } else {
            queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("sendTime:>" + sendTime));
        }
    }
    SearchResponse response = transportClient.prepareSearch(ChatSettings.ELASTIC_MESSAGE_INDEX_NAME + "*")
            .setTypes(ChatSettings.ELASTIC_DB_NAME)
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
            .setQuery(queryBuilder)
            .setFetchSource(new String[]{"id"}, null)
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.count("count").field("id"))
            .setSize(1)
            .setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
    checkResponse(response);

    InternalValueCount count = response.getAggregations().get("count");
return response.getHits().getTotalHits() > 0 ? count.getValue() : null;
```

for example: for messageThreadId = 1020 it will return 5 as answer, for messageThreadId = 1030 there is no answer in this condition so I got null that is true. and for messageThreadId = 1040 it will return 20 as the answer and its true. but I want a query That I sent a list of messageThreadIds list [1020,1030,1040] and get 25 as the answer. but when I change the messageThreadId condition query to 
    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("messageThread" ,messageThreadIdList ));

it will return null as the answer!
is there a way to have a query for my purpose?

Comment: r u using rest high level client?

Comment: @user7851946 no, we are using TransportClient

Answer (score 0):

you basically want to match multiple terms with you data, so you could use a terms query for the same.

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "messageThread" : ["messageThread1", "messageThread2"]
        }
    }
}
```

You can use

```
//it can accept a collection
List<String> messageTgreads;
 QueryBuilders.termsQuery("messageThread", messageTgreads)
```

and depending on the client you use you can fire the query accordingly.

Comment: thank you so much! but when I use    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("messageThread:" , messageThreadIds)); I get the null answer! but for each value of message thread id there is some document and answer

Comment: can you share your documents and the response you are expecting, then I will be able to suggest you a better query

Comment: sure, I have edited my question and added more detail

Comment: can you share one document from you index as well. need to see whether messageThread is an array of int or how it is stored?

Comment: {
        "_index": "chat_message_new_201805",
        "_type": "fbpm",
        "_id": "35",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "excludedUsers": [],
          "isDeleted": false,
          "messageType": 0,
          "sender": 1,
          "messageId": 1239323,
          "sendTimeNanos": 949000000,
          "id": 35,
          "text": "Hello World :D",
          "messageThread": 32,
          "uniqueId": "01c9204d-4b0e-4a80-bd52-122671b50856",
          "sendTime": 1527502039949
        }
      },

Comment: it's stored as a string

Comment: basically you are doing an "and" between all message threads by using "must" query whereas from your question it looks that you want an "or" between them, So just loop over the list of mesaage threads and add "should" clause for each message thread